# Epilepsy classification using Welch method power spectral density

Tags: csv, signal-processing, psd

from mne.time_frequency import psd_welch
ImportError: cannot import name 'psd_welch' from 'mne.time_frequency' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mne/time_frequency/**init**.py)

Comment: my code is
 from mne.time_frequency import psd_welch
def eeg_power_band(epochs):
    FREQ_BANDS = {"delta": [0.5, 4.5],
                  "theta": [4.5, 8.5],
                  "alpha": [8.5, 11.5],
                  "sigma": [11.5, 15.5],
                  "beta": [15.5, 30],
                  "gamma": [30, 45],
                  }

    psds, freqs = psd_welch(epochs, picks='eeg', fmin=0.5, fmax=45)# Compute the PSD using the Welch's method
    psds /= np.sum(psds, axis=-1, keepdims=True)    # Normalize the PSDs

Comment: Please edit you question to add additional details rather than post them in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

try installing the "mne" python module by executing :

`pip install mne==1.0.3`

Comment: Look at the error message: mne is already installed.